# AngularJS - preselected drobox issue

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with the pre-selected select box,
in the database field value of selected subjects stored in this format: `["12","3","37"]`

PHP code read value from database:

```
$data['classSubject']=json_decode($data['subjects'],true);
```

And then pass it to the app.js file:

```
 $scope.edit = function(id) {
   showHideLoad();
   dataFactory.httpRequest('index.php/students/'+id).then(function(data) {
     $scope.changeView('edit');
     $scope.form = data;
     $scope.SelectedSubjects = data.classSubject;             
     console.log(data.classSubject);
     showHideLoad(true);
   });
 }
```

And HTML file:

```
<select class="form-control selecBox" name="classSubject[]" multiple required id="classSubj"> 
  <option ng-repeat="subject in form.allsubjects track by $index" value="{{subject.id}}" ng-selected="form.classSubject.indexOf(subject.id)>-1">{{subject.subjectTitle}}</option> 
</select>
```

The big issue i am facing here is:

1. When I pass  value  of selected subjects (`$data['classSubject']=json_decode($data['subjects'],true);`)

It wont preselect from select box, if read as simple string :

```
$data['classSubject']=$data['subjects']
```

Then (`ng-selected="form.classSubject.indexOf(subject.id)>-1"`) works but it select wrong entries, I suppose pre selected subjects are `["3"]` selecting both options with `value="3"` and `value="37"` even 38, 39 and so on.

Please let me know the reason why this happens!

Comment: consider using `data.data`. E.g. `$scope.form = data.data;`. Or replace `.then` to `.success`  (an older syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the default highlight didn't work with any of stackover's code editor angular version. But works in the latest stable version **1.6.9**. Please check on your angular version too.

```js
angular
.module('sample', [])
.controller('simpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = [
    {value: '1', name: 'option 1'},
    {value: '2', name: 'option 2'},
    {value: '3', name: 'option 3'},
    {value: '4', name: 'option 4'},
    {value: '5', name: 'option 5'}
  ];
  $scope.selectedOptions = ['1', '4'];
  
  $scope.intOptions = $scope.options.map(m => ({value: Number(m.value), name: m.name}));
  $scope.selectedIntOptions = [1, 4];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sample" ng-controller="simpleController">
  <hr>
  <label for="multipleoptionsasstring"> Multiple select with values as string: </label><br>
  <select name="multipleoptionsasstring" ng-model="selectedOptions" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <div>selected : {{selectedOptions}}</div>

  <hr>
  <label for="multipleoptionsasint"> Multiple select with values as int: </label><br>
  <select name="multipleoptionsasint" ng-model="selectedIntOptions" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="option in intOptions" ng-value="option.value">{{option.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <div>selected : {{selectedIntOptions}}</div>
</div>
```